# User can login without permission

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

When user press (X) UPPER RIGHT CORNER user can login without permission

```
Private Sub LoginForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim LoginForm As Boolean
    If LoginForm = True Then
        Application.[Restart]()
    End If
    If login Is False Then
        Application.[Exit]()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClosed(ByVal e As EventArgs)
   Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it line by line to see what it actually does and how that differs from your expectation.  You need to ALWAYS do that before posting here.

Comment: The `Dim LoginForm As Boolean` line creates an local Boolean variable with a default value of `False`. The `If LoginForm = True` code can **never** run. It seems like this value might be hiding something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Private Sub LoginForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles LoginForm.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
          e.Cancel = True
          Application.[Exit]()
    End If
End Sub
```